# Write activity needed to split dynamodb stream into multiple shards?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-kinesis

I am writing to DynamoDB table at 350 writes/second. I have enabled streams on it and have configured multiple consumers to read from each shard. Each consumer is able to handle only 100 records/seconds which means I would need at least 4 consumers processing the stream. Issue is that DynamoDB is not creating multiple shards when writes/second increases. Want to know at what point DynamoDB starts creating multiple shards (value of writes/second)

I have tried writing into the table between 100 writes to 350 writes per second

What can be done to trigger multiple shards, from the documentation, there is no way to issue API to trigger sharding/resharding on dynamodb stream

Comment: This article give you a good insight on partitioning

https://shinesolutions.com/2016/06/27/a-deep-dive-into-dynamodb-partitions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do this. The sharding is handled automatically and based on table partitions.

As an alternative, you could have a consumer that reads from the DynamoDB stream and forwards the records to another stream, where you can control the number of shards.